# SVG - stroke-width not working even applied to svg g path

Tags: svg

I have applied svg stroke-width to svg > g > path. But it is not decreasing the stroke width. Any help on this would be really appreciated.

```
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 512" height="100" width="100">
<g id="angle-right1_layer">
<path stroke-width="0.1" d="M224.3 273l-136 136c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.6-22.6c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9l96.4-96.4-96.4-96.4c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9L54.3 103c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l136 136c9.5 9.4 9.5 24.6.1 34z"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Show how what you're seeing is different from what you expect to see. Note that stroke width of 0.1 is a very fine line under normal zoom so results will depend on your scale. Also show relevant CSS for `#angle-right1_layer`

Comment: Convert your SVG to a [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you might be confused - because there are many other questions like this: this shape is not made with a stroke - this is made with a filled path. If you add a "fill=none" and stroke-width="2" you can clearly see this. Just checking.

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 512" height="100" width="100">
<g id="angle-right1_layer">
<path stroke-width="4" stroke="black" d="M224.3 273l-136 136c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.6-22.6c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9l96.4-96.4-96.4-96.4c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9L54.3 103c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l136 136c9.5 9.4 9.5 24.6.1 34z" fill="none"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```